# Includes & Forward Declaration in C++

Tags: c++, include, forward-declaration

I've read through lots of threads on this, and followed the instructions at http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/HeaderFileIncludePatterns.htm, but I am still getting problems with includes.

To make sure I didn't have some other error in my real code, I wrote and attempted to compile the following code exactly.

*A.h:*

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    void myMethod() const;
};
#endif
```

*A.cpp:*

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>
void A::myMethod() const
{
    std::cout << "Hooray!" << std::endl;
}
```

*B.h:*

```
class A;

#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
class B
{
    const A* aInstance;
public:
    B(){};
    void useA() const;
};
#endif
```

*B.cpp:*

```
#include "B.h"

void B::useA() const
{
    aInstance.myMethod();
}
```

*main.cpp:*

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    B bInstance;
    bInstance.useA();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile Command: `g++ main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp`

Error:

```
B.cpp: In member function ‘void B::useA() const’:
B.cpp:5:15: error: request for member ‘myMethod’ in ‘((const B*)this)->B::aInstance’, which is of non-class type ‘const A* const’
```

I'm really starting to get frustrated. How do I get class B to use Class A? We didn't get to pointers and bigger projects in the C++ class I took, and from what I read, I really feel as if I understand what's supposed to be going on here, but I don't know why it isn't working.

Thanks for any assistance. You'll make my entire weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's:

```
aInstance->myMethod();
```

not

```
aInstance.myMethod();
```

since `aInstance` is a pointer to `A`, not an `A` object.

Also, in `B.cpp`, you need to `#include "A.h"`.

EDIT:

Your code leads to **undefined behavior**. `aInstance` is not initialized, and you're calling `myMethod` in it. Since it is not a `virtual` method and you're not accessing any of `A`'s members, it will probably work, but nevertheless, it's wrong. You should initialize it in `B`'s constructor:

```
B() : aInstance(new A) {};
```

Comment: You and Nawaz combined make a complete answer. Thank you!

Comment: Since you got it first, I'll accept yours once I'm allowed to.

Comment: @TomThorogood I edited my answer, there's also another issue with the code.

Comment: Oh. And thanks for the added info.  I will make those changes too.

Answer (score 1):

In `B.cpp` include `A.h` as well:

```
#include "A.h"  //include this as well
#include "B.h"

void B::useA() const
{
    aInstance->myMethod(); //also use -> not .
}
```

`A.h` is included so that the compiler may know that `aInstance` has a member function called `myMethod`.

Comment: You and Luchian combined make a complete answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: If that is the complete and actual code, then YES. He needs to initialize the `aInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to instantiate the object

```
const A* aInstance;
```

and then change the code

```
void B::useA() const
{
    aInstance->myMethod();
}
```